# Elisp regex matching - evaluate as region vs as individual sexp gives different answers

Tags: regular-expressions, string

Here's a chunk of code:

```
(defvar test-string "bla bla bla 10.10.10.10 bla bla bla")

(string-match "[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+" test-string)
(message (match-string 0 test-string))
```

When I select the entire block it's evaluated correctly (using `eval-region`):

```
10.10.10.10
```

When I evaluate sequentially (using `eval-last-sexp`) I get the following:

```
bla bla bla 10.1
```

I've looked at the docs of the respective functions but couldn't find any help.

My Emacs version is `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1347.57)`.

Comment: I don't have an `eval-current-form-sp`, where does it come from?

Comment: Ah! Apptly it comes with spacemacs. I'll post it's definition

Comment: @db48x I've changed it to use the stock emacs function. Still weird behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you evaluate sequentially, there is a boat load of Elisp code executed between those to statements, and of course, this Elisp code will almost inevitably end up using regular expressions, so the `match-data` of your first expression will be long gone by the time you run the second.

What kind of Elisp code might be run between the two?  Let's see:

- the code that you trigger when you try and move the cursor to the second expression
- the code of eval-last-sexp
- the code to recompute the mode-line, and frame title
- maybe some background timers
- possibly some font-lock refresh
- maybe some procees filter
- ...

`match-data` is very much transient, if not fleeting, so you have to use it *right* after you've performed the regexp match.  If you're not sure if you do it quickly enough, then you can generally assume that it's not soon enough (i.e. assume that all functions can destroy the match-data, except for a few core functions like `car`, `cdr`, ...).

Comment: Coming back to this answer again, I realized it's a pretty bad software engineering in my opinion... Maybe it'd be worth communicating it to the Emacs maintainers.

Comment: No doubt it's a bad design.  But it's kinda late to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`C-h f match-string:

```
Return string of text matched by last search.
```

Likely that call to `string-match` was *not* the last search (maybe check the definition of command `eval-last-sexp` etc.).

Judging by the position values shown in the error message, the last match was against buffer text. Try using `save-match-data`.

Answer (score 0):

`string-match` sets global state which `match-string` uses. If you did another match (which many commands might do internally), then this global data will be from a different match, and will have different saved start and end points. The error you mention is because the saved start and end points were outside the string you passed to `match-string`.